# How to import a Java library in Eclipse?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, import

I have downloaded and am trying to import this library: https://github.com/sachin-handiekar/jInstagram in one of my projects. However, whenever I point to the directory where this project is located and try to import it, Eclipse says "No projects are found to import." I even tried importing it as Android code but it didn't recognize it either. How do I import and use this library in my Android project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It says no projects are found to import because it is looking for the eclipse .project file which is not included in git repositories. Try the import file system option

Or better yet, try out the [git plugin](http://www.eclipse.org/egit/) for eclipse

Answer (score 2):

Just to use this library within your project add it as a [Maven](http://maven.apache.org/) dependency

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.sachinhandiekar</groupId>
   <artifactId>jInstagram</artifactId>
   <version>1.0.9</version>
</dependency>
```

If you don't know how to do this check this plugin: [maven-android-plugin](https://code.google.com/p/maven-android-plugin/)

You can also checkout the complete source tree for the project and then go to the directory containing the pom.xml file and using Maven run `mvn install` to build this project and then import it to the Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

Its easy, in Activity press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd>